# Python script to run multiple processes using subprocess.call and get their pids

Tags: python, subprocess

I have created a script that is reading the paths of scripts from a config file and then using the subprocess module I am running those paths sequentially.
My script is as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import configparser
import argparse as ap
import subprocess
import sys
import shlex
import os
import signal

def file_reader():
        config_dict = {}
        configParser = configparser.ConfigParser()

        configParser.read('config.ini')
        for section_name in configParser.sections():
                for (each_key, each_value) in configParser.items(section_name):
                        config_dict[each_key] = each_value
                config_dict = dict(configParser.items(section_name))
                reversed_dictionary = dict(map(reversed, configParser.items(section_name)))
                list_vals = list(config_dict.values())
                list_keys = list(config_dict.keys())
                return config_dict, reversed_dictionary

def main():
        config_dict, reversed_dictionary = file_reader()
        for key,val in config_dict.items():
                print(key)
                print(config_dict[key])
        parser = ap.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('-s', '--start', help='start script', action='store_true')
        parser.add_argument('-q', '--stop', help='stop script', action='store_true')
        args = parser.parse_args()

        if args.start and args.stop:
                print("error")
        elif args.start:
                for k,v in reversed_dictionary.items():
                        print(k, "=", v )
                        if(reversed_dictionary[k] == v):
                                proc = subprocess.call([k], shell=True, close_fds=True)
                if proc != 0:
                        if proc < 0:
                                print("\nKilled by signal!", -proc)
                        else:
                                print("\nReturn code is:", proc)
                else:
                        print("\nSuccess")
                sys.exit(0)
        elif args.stop:
                kill_process()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
                main()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                exit()
```

My config file is as follows:

```
[my-config]
path1 = /usr/local/src/sipp-3.3/sipp -i 10.171.0.202 -mi 10.171.0.202 -sf HA_demo.xml -inf HA_demo.csv 10.171.0.231:5060 -p 5060 -r 1 -rp 1s -l 1 -m 1 -watchdog_minor_threshold 1500 -trace_err -aa -d 350s -oocsn ooc_default -t u1 -trace_screen -skip_rlimit
path2 = /home/asad.javed/script.py
path3 = /home/asad.javed/stop-services.sh
```

There are problems that I have not able been able to resolve yet.

1. I want to be able to run the child processes individually in a sequential manner from subprocess.call and get the pid of each process. The child process in this case is the paths to scripts I have given in the config file.
2. I want to be able to get pid of each child process and do additional work on it such as kill the process using the pid i.e. if the child process gets stuck during execution.
3. The other problem I am experiencing is that while executing the script I am always getting the return code as **1** even though the script has executed successfully in which case the exit status should be **0**.

I am new to the Python world and help will be very much appreciated if someone clarifies above issues I am facing.

Comment: You can use `subprocess.Popen` instead.

Comment: I have tried that but  I am experiencing the same issues as with subprocess.call.

Comment: Given you are using `shell=True`, I believe the returncode you get is that returned by the shell. Is it possible the shell is changing that returncode?

Comment: Unrelated to subprocess, doing `for k, v in reversed_dictionary.items()` and then `if reversed_dictionary[k] == v` is redundant. By the way the [items](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) method of dictionaries works, this will always be true.

Comment: I have also removed the shell argument but still I am getting return code as 1. The script is running successfully and I don't see any syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

### Run child processes sequentially and get the pid

```
import subprocess
commands = ["date", "myscript.sh"]
child_processes = []
for cmd in commands:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    child_processes.append(proc)
    print(proc.pid)
```

### Do additional work

```
for proc in child_processes:
    try:
        outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)
    except TimeoutExpired:
        proc.kill()
        outs, errs = proc.communicate()
```

### Notes

See [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). The [Popen object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) has methods to poll or communicate with the subprocess and also has properties for the pid.